# Best way to manage laravel 5 logs for each event

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5.1

I wants to logs for each events happened in my website. I would like to know what will be the best way to handle this?

I looked at the packages available but it's not in my requirement.

Let say I wants to record every email activity went through the system plus all insert/update/delete performed by the system user.

I saw EventListener but each time I have to fire an event from the controller I would love if is there any way if I just have to write one time code at somewhere so anytime insert/update/delete happened It will be recorded yes plus emails as well.

Help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't down vote without any description. Specify the appropriate reason.

Answer (score 0):

**/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Log;

public function boot()
{
    DB::listen(function ($event) {
        Log::info('Running SQL query: '.$event->sql);
    });
    //...
}
```

That will push an info entry on every query that's executed on the website. Have a look at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors) for specific information on the Log levels.

Comment: $event->sql saying that -- Trying to get property of non-object